# AOSP contribution commit fail [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'java'

Tags: java, android, android-source

`repo upload` gives me

```
eric@eric-VirtualBox:~/android-11/libcore$ repo upload
[COMMIT a9b8b9106b20] Signed-off-by: Eric <ericntd@gmail.com>
[FAILED] checkstyle-luni-json-xml
    [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'java'
[FAILED] checkstyle-ojluni
    [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'java'
[FAILED] repohooks for platform/libcore failed in 0.133s

FATAL: Preupload failed due to above error(s).
For more info, please see:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/repohooks/
ERROR: pre-upload hooks exited with exit code: 1
```

But it's unclear to me what's wrong

Here's what I see when I `git commit --amend`

```
  GNU nano 4.8                                      /home/eric/android-11/libcore/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG                                                 
Signed-off-by: Eric <ericntd@gmail.com>
Change-Id: I06188772b9cbc6622166871a35a05a60d1c6bc4b

Fixed NullPointerException crash NetworkInterface

Was informed that the issue has been fixed for Android S/ 12
(see issuetracker)
but not 11 where it's number one crashes for some apps

Bug: 204913332
Test: covered by NetworkInterfaceTest

Change-Id: I1e91f5a2f952f210504fb54150725b672e46adb6

# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
#
# Date:      Fri Dec 17 15:56:42 2021 -0500
#
# On branch fix-npe-networkinterface
# Changes to be committed:
#       modified:   ojluni/src/main/java/java/net/NetworkInterface.java
#
# Untracked files:
#       .idea/
#       benchmarks/benchmarks.iml
#       dalvik/src/main/main5.iml
...
```

And `git log` gives me:

```
eric@eric-VirtualBox:~/android-11/libcore$ git log
commit 797db88d4be7daa4e00265a8b8588d71274aee47 (HEAD -> fix-npe-networkinterface)
Author: Eric <ericntd@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Dec 17 15:56:42 2021 -0500

    Signed-off-by: Eric <ericntd@gmail.com>
    Change-Id: I06188772b9cbc6622166871a35a05a60d1c6bc4b
    
    Fixed NullPointerException crash NetworkInterface
    
    Was informed that the issue has been fixed for Android S/ 12
    (see issuetracker)
    but not 11 where it's number one crashes for some apps
    
    Bug: 204913332
    Test: covered by NetworkInterfaceTest
    
    Change-Id: I1e91f5a2f952f210504fb54150725b672e46adb6

commit be231aa384e6ffb2807af24d8b9d9919394a6c8a (tag: android-security-11.0.0_r50, tag: android-security-11.0.0_r49, tag: m/android-security-11.0.0_r50, aosp/android11-security-release)
Author: Pete Bentley <prb@google.com>
Date:   Fri Dec 4 09:26:35 2020 +0000

    Reject non-ASCII hostnames and SANs.
    
    Updates test expectations to match OkHostnameVerifier behaviour changes
    in the same topic.
    
    Bug: 171980069
    Test: atest CtsLibcoreTestCases CtsLibcoreOkHttpTestCases
    Change-Id: I7ccd2c6d4255d29112e9a6d58640316c364bf67a
    (cherry picked from commit 650e71cc3acbc3f5af2ae312bc5ed71bb2d7c20b)
```